# Error: Could not find or load main class in Java Maven project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am working in Java Maven project. There is a `.bat` file in the root of the project which invokes a Java class with some arguments something like this:

```
java my.package.MyClass abc hi 1
```

Now, my project jar is built in the target directory of that project when I do `mvn clean install`. When I run that `.bat` file it gives me the below error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class my.package.MyClass
```

Project's `pom.xml` only contains jars as dependency.

Do I need to do something in `pom.xml` to make it work?

Comment: Can you show your pom file and the folder layout you are using? And how the `.bat` file looks like?

Answer (score 6):

please provide your `pom.xml` so we can look for it,
anyway,

do you use `maven-jar-plugin`?

something like this

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <configuration>
     <archive>
       <manifest>
         <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
         <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
         <mainClass>your.main.class.package.ClassName</mainClass> // your main class
       </manifest>
     </archive>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

and try to run your `*.jar` with command `java -jar yourjar.jar`